# Help in a proof of primitive root theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question is regarding the theorem 2' page 44 in Rosen's book - A classical introduction to modern number theory.

At some point in the proof, the author argues that if:
$$
(-1)^{a}5^{b} \equiv (-1)^{a'}5^{b'} (\text{mod} \quad 2^{l}) \quad (l \geq 3)
$$
Then:
$$
(-1)^{a} \equiv (-1)^{a'} (\text{mod} \quad 4)
$$

Where we should use the fact that $2^{l-2}$ is the order of 5 mod $2^l$.

I have not managed to understand why the above implication is true. Could anyone help me?

Comment: If it were otherwise we'd have $5^b\equiv -5^{b'}\pmod {2^l}$, whence, taking $b>b'$ wlog, $5^{b-b'}\equiv -1\pmod {2^l}$, but that last congruence has no solution even $\pmod 4$.

Comment: if $(-1)^a5^b\equiv(-1)^{a'}5^{b'}\pmod {2^l}$ then $(-1)^a5^b\equiv(-1)^{a'}5^{b'}\pmod 4$, and $5\equiv1\pmod4$ so $(-1)^a\equiv(-1)^{a'}\pmod 4$

Answer (score 1):

$$(-1)^{a}5^{b} \equiv (-1)^{a'}5^{b'} (\text{mod} \quad 2^{l}) \quad (l \geq 3)
$$
$\implies$ $2^l$ divides $(-1)^{a}5^{b}-(-1)^{a'}5^{b'}$

$\implies$ $2^2=4$ divides $(-1)^{a}5^{b}-(-1)^{a'}5^{b'}$
But since $5 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ the claim follows.